# How do I move class to separate document?

Tags: java

In this code, I would like to move the `Dollar`class to a separate `.java`file. What kind of import statements will I then need to add in this file? Do I need to make adjustments to `CLASSPATH`? I work on Mac OS X.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class TestDollar
{
    class Dollar
    {
        int amount;

        Dollar(int amount)
        {
        }

        void times(int multiplier)
        {
        }
    }

    public void testMultiplication()
    {
        Dollar five = new Dollar(5);
        five.times(2);
        assertEquals(10, five.amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do u mean by 'move'? you want to have a separate file for it?

Comment: well, yes. I'd like to have a separate file for it. Is that not clear from my question? It does say "...separate `.java` file".

Comment: can't you create another .java file and put the class' code in it? it wont require any change as long as u create the java file in the same folder(package). 
btw::: **Is that not clear from my question?** is it a language for requesting answer?

Comment: you ask if I want to have a separate file for it, which I clearly state in my original post, so yes, I wonder how else I should state this request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create another class named Dollar and the import it in your class TestDollar using the instruction import yourpackage.Dollar;
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `Dollar` will remain in the same package you don't need any imports. You will need changes in the classpath if both these files are going to reside in different locations.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is interested, I now have a file with the `Dollar` class called Dollar.java:

```
class Dollar
{
    int amount;

    Dollar(int amount)
    {
    }

    void times(int multiplier)
    {
    }
}
```

and a file with the test, called `TestDollar.java`:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class TestDollar
{
    public void testMultiplication()
    {
        Dollar five = new Dollar(5);
        five.times(2);
        assertEquals(10, five.amount);
    }
}
```

The test is run by calling `javac TestDollar.java`.
In my .bash_profile, I set

```
export CLASSPATH=/Users/machine/programming/tdd/junit-4.11.jar
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/machine/programming/tdd
```

and the directory contains the `junit-4.11.jar` and `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar` files.